# Python and Swagger 2 - import class for nested object not working correctly

Tags: python-3.x, flask, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I have a problem with code generate from Swagger-Codegen.

I have created the following object definitions with Swagger:

```
...
definitions:
  Object1:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      id:
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"
      obj2:
        $ref: "#/definitions/Object2"
  Object2:
    type: "object"
    properties:
      id:
        type: "integer"
        format: "int64"
      name:
        type: "string"
...
```

I then exported the YAML file and generated the stub server for python-flask.

When I try to start the flask server I get the error:

```py
NameError: name 'Object2' is not defined
```

The `__init__.py` file was automatically generated and contains the import for the classes of both models:

```
from swagger.models.object1 import Object1
from swagger.models.object2 import Object2
```

If I add an import to the `Object2` class I get this error instead:

**object1.py**

```
from swagger.models import Object2
```

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Object2' from partially initialized module 'swagger.models' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

The error only resolves if I add this import to **object1.py**:

```
from swagger.models.object2 import Object2
```

Since the code is generated and any changes would be lost, is there a way to import the `Object2` class?

I tried to edit the **model.mustache** template, but was unable to find a way to allow the import of the models I need.

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue, the problem is that swagger was creating all imports as absolute import, which does not work for a package. What you need is relative import

instead of:
`from swagger.models.entity import Entity`

you should do:
`from .entity import Entity`